# Erro com bind_param() com conexão PDO mysql

Tags: php, pdo

se alguém puder me ajudar no erro no script eu agradeço muito, o erro é o seguinte:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in

o código é esse:

```
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"en_US");
    if(isset($_POST["id"])) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $product[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }   

    $statement = app('db')->prepare("SELECT as_produtos.nome, as_produtos.preco FROM as_produtos WHERE id=? LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bind_param('s', $product['id']);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($product_name, $product_price);

    while($statement->fetch()){ 
        $product["product_name"] = $product_name;
        $product["product_price"] = $product_price;     
        if(isset($_SESSION["products"])){ 
            if(isset($_SESSION["products"][$product['id']])) {              
                $_SESSION["products"][$product['id']]["product_qty"] = $_SESSION["products"][$product['id']]["product_qty"] + $_POST["product_qty"];                
            } else {
                $_SESSION["products"][$product['id']] = $product;
            }           
        } else {
            $_SESSION["products"][$product['id']] = $product;
        }   
    }   
    $total_product = count($_SESSION["products"]);
    die(json_encode(array('products'=>$total_product)));
    }

    if(isset($_GET["remove_code"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
    $product_code  = filter_var($_GET["remove_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if(isset($_SESSION["products"][$product_code])) {
        unset($_SESSION["products"][$product_code]);
    }   
    $total_product = count($_SESSION["products"]);
    die(json_encode(array('products'=>$total_product)));
    }

    if(isset($_GET["update_quantity"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"])) {   
    if(isset($_GET["quantity"]) && $_GET["quantity"]>0) {       
        $_SESSION["products"][$_GET["update_quantity"]]["product_qty"] = $_GET["quantity"]; 
    }
    $total_product = count($_SESSION["products"]);
    die(json_encode(array('products'=>$total_product)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu acho que você pode ter se enganado o bind_param é usado apenas quando você faz conexão com o banco de dados utilizando new MySQLi ou mysqli_connect

você pode conferir aqui https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

No seu caso você deve utilizar o bindParam

você pode encontrar todas informações na documentação aqui 
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Obrigado amigo, sua resposta foi de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Segue o código (carrinho de compras) com a solução encaminhada pelo amigo Artsher Developer.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY,"pt_BR");

# add products in cart 
if(isset($_POST["id"])) {
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) :
    $product[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
endforeach; 

 $statement = app('db')->prepare("SELECT as_produtos.nome, as_produtos.preco FROM as_produtos WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
 $statement->bindParam(':id', $product['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $statement->execute();

foreach($statement as $dados_produto) :

    $product["product_name"] = $dados_produto["nome"];
    $product["product_price"] = $dados_produto["preco"];

    if(isset($product["product_name"])){ 

        if(isset($_SESSION["products"][$product['id']])) {              
            $_SESSION["products"][$product['id']]["product_qty"] = $_SESSION["products"][$product['id']]["product_qty"] + $_POST["product_qty"];

        } else {
            $_SESSION["products"][$product['id']] = $product;
        }   

    } else {
        $_SESSION["products"][$product['id']] = $product;
    }   

endforeach;

$total_product = count($_SESSION["products"]);
die(json_encode(array('products'=>$total_product)));
}

# Remove products from cart
if(isset($_GET["remove_code"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"])) {
$product_code  = filter_var($_GET["remove_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if(isset($_SESSION["products"][$product_code])) {
    unset($_SESSION["products"][$product_code]);
}   
$total_product = count($_SESSION["products"]);
die(json_encode(array('products'=>$total_product)));
}

# Update cart product quantity
if(isset($_GET["update_quantity"]) && isset($_SESSION["products"])) {   
if(isset($_GET["quantity"]) && $_GET["quantity"]>0) {       
    $_SESSION["products"][$_GET["update_quantity"]]["product_qty"] = 
$_GET["quantity"];  
}
$total_product = count($_SESSION["products"]);
die(json_encode(array('products'=>$total_product)));
}
```